# R - using XPath in rvest gives error "Unexpected character"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a website that I'm trying to scrap . I've found the proper html tag that I want to scrap and copied its XPath that looks like this:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul
```

Next I use rvest:

```
library(rvest)
my_website <- read_html("http://www...") # a full link to the website
links <- html_nodes(my_website, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul/")
```

and I get the following error:

> Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 1.

I'm not really fluent in webscrapping, so could anyone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try specifying the selector type as xpath like so: `links <- html_elements(my_website, xpath = "/html/body/etc")` without trailing slash (note that `html_elements` superseded `html_nodes`)

Comment: @I_O Thanks. I've changed the code. Now it does not produce an error but retrieves an empty string instead of the content of the tag. So, still no success

Comment: Tag content needs still to be extracted from the result of `html_elements()` with `text_html2()` or, in raw form `text_html()`.

Comment: Can you give us the website you are considering to extract the information? That would be useful to provide a solution.